# Installing stackless python, how to get modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've followed the instructions found here: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/install-stackless-python and installed stackless. Stackless itself works, but unlike what the tutorial said I cannot import my python2.7 modules into the stackless python installation. What do I need to do to make it work?

Edit: When I try to import my old modules into stackless, for example:

```
>>>import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

Stackless can't find the module.

Comment: "I cannot import my python2.7 modules" - what happens if you try? Adding the explicit (or even trivial) error may help. And where did you install the "my modules" on your system? Is it in any of the `os.path` elements you're supposed to add as mentioned in the tutorial?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify. I followed all the steps in the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

*Edited the answer from the question.*

> There was an error in the tutorial, in the line
>
> ```
> sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ /opt/stackless/lib/python2.7/site-packages
> ```
>
> When I removed the link, and instead ran
>
> ```
> sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ /opt/stackless/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
> ```
>
> Everything worked as expected, and I now can import my old modules as
>   usual within stackless python.